# display some portion of the wordpress post outside of wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

i have wordpress blog in my custom built website, i am displaying some posts from wordpress blog into my website based on tags like below

```
require('../news/wp-blog-header.php');
                            $query = new WP_Query('tag=Dalaman');

                            if ($query->have_posts()):
                                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                                    ?>
                                    <h3> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                    <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                                    <?php
                                endwhile;
                            endif;
```

`the_content` displays the `10 posts` from wordpress database based on `WP_Query`

**Problem:** i want to display some part of the post, let's say 55 chracters
posts, in my db dont have `excerpt` by default and i dont want to use `the_exerpt()` as it strips html tags and my post contains `<img>` on start of every post

i tried many things but all went in vain,i also used php's `substr()` function, but it didn't work in this case.

so how can i display somepart of the post along with image ?

very much thanks.

Kind Regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like below,

```
$limit = 55;
                            $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);

                            if (count($content) >= $limit) {
                                array_pop($content);
                                $content = implode(" ", $content) . '...';
                            } else {
                                $content = implode(" ", $content);
                            }
                            $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/', '', $content);
                            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                            $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
                            echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

I suggest you do what the article says and insert a `<!--more-->` at the breakpoints whenever - this is more safer than stripping an arbitrary amount of characters because you may break your html tags that way.

If you're not concerned about that, then instead of

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

do

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content(); //get the content as a string
$content = substr($content, 0, 55); //cut the first 55 characters
echo $content; //display it as usual
?>
```

Comment: and also i have imported all posts from other cutom blog entries, so posts dont have `<!--more-->` and i acnt modify all posts as they are more 2000 in counting, so have to do it in this way, i dont know why

Comment: *How* is this "not working"? Do you get an error, do you get an unwanted result?

Comment: its giving me unwanted result :-(

Comment: Which result do you get? Come on, somebody wrote an answer for you, please give some reasonable feedback how it is not working. How else are they expected to improve the answer?

Comment: BTW Cakephp has good `truncate()` function in its String utilities. It does observe HTML tags and can probably be easily used elsewhere. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/49a455a2cb31829f452067253288834b360bf203/lib/Cake/Utility/String.php#L419

Comment: oops, please accept my apology(it only happened due to english is not my first language, it happens many times, sorry once again) for not being reasonable, well i am getting posts in a strange way, my html gets change, i can see posts data but not post content

Comment: would that function help in this matter ?